# Copy same assets block on different html documents with grunt-usemin

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

I'm using grunt-usemin in grunt for minify, concat all the js files and put them into minified file on my index.html header:

```
<!-- build:js js/indexBulk.js -->
    <script src="js/common/mifirstfile.js"></script>
    <script src="js/common/errors.js"></script>
    <script src="js/common/anotherfile.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
 <!-- endbuild -->
```

This works perfect...but what if I have some others html static files with exactly the same js files on the header, how do I have to proceed in order to prevent the fact of copy each time this block?

Is there a way to put the minified file on the header of each one of my others html files without copying this block?